# FrameLayout setOffscreenPageLimit?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-framelayout

is this possible ? I use framelayout to display the contents of my fragment with the use of navigation drawer. What i want to happen is to keep the state of the fragment even if i go to another fragment.

I have a vague idea on whats causing the reload which is this.

```
private Fragment getProfileFragment() {
    switch (navItemIndex) {
        case 0:
            // home
            ProfileLO profileLO = new ProfileLO();
            return profileLO;
        case 1:
            LocationLO locationLO = new LocationLO();
            return locationLO;
        case 2:
            FarmGoodsLO farmGoodsLO = new FarmGoodsLO();
            return farmGoodsLO;
        case 3:
            RentEquipLO rentEquipLO = new RentEquipLO();
            return rentEquipLO;
        default:
            return new ProfileLO();
    }
}
```

Is there any hack out there?

Comment: you always create a new fragment before showing it. If you want to save states, you shouldn't create new fragments all the time

Comment: any suggestions on how to show fragment without creating them ? well i know how in viewpager but not in framelayout

Comment: same way - store them in variables